# Actualizar archivo csv con Github actions

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit, github-actions

Tengo un script **temblores.py** en python el cual realiza un scrap a un sitio web de sismos y genera un archivo csv **data.csv**

Estoy intentando actualizar el archivo mediante Github actions pero aún no logro que se pueda actualizar, le adjunto la actions

````
on:
      schedule:
            - cron: "*/5  * * * *" #runs at 00:00 UTC everyday
jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        
        steps:
          - name: actualizar sismos
            uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout the repository content to github runner.
          - name: setup python
            uses: actions/setup-python@v2
            with:
              persist-credentials: false 
              fetch-depth: 0
         # Python 3.7
          - name: Inicializando Python 3.7
            uses: actions/setup-python@v1
            with:
               python-version: 3.7
          - name: Install dependencies
            run: |
             python -m pip install --upgrade pip
             pip install flake8 pytest
             if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
          - name: Lint with flake8
            run: |
             python temblores.py
             
              # Push a main
          - name: Pull main
            run: |
             git config --local user.email "email@gmail.com"
             git config --local user.name "username"
             git add -A
             git commit -m "data.csv" -a
             
          #- name: commit
            #run: |
               #git add data.csv
              # git commit -m "data.csv"```
````

Comment: hay algo como un log?

Comment: No, la action se ejecuta bien sin problemas, pero no actualiza el archico

Comment: Quiza esto funcione: [write-csv-file-action](https://github.com/gr2m/write-csv-file-action#fetch-stats-and-update-file-in-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, de acuerdo al ejemplo que tenés, falta hacer **push** del commit.

Asumiendo que el archivo `data.csv` realmente existe y se cambió, sólo tenés que hacer `git push origin main`.

```
 - name: Push a main
            run: |
             git config --local user.email "email@gmail.com"
             git config --local user.name "username"
             git add -u # La flag -u añade sólo los cambios de archivos existentes en git
             git commit -m "data.csv cambió"
             git push origin main
```

Acá podés encontrar un ejemplo parecido: https://lannonbr.com/blog/2019-12-09-git-commit-in-actions

**EDIT:**
Yo haría `git add data.csv` en vez de `git add -u` y no usaría un email válido, porque los bots son felices tratando de encontrar correos para spamear.

Comment: como podria agregar de otra manera el mail.?

Comment: No hay necesidad. El email y el nombre son meramente informativos y le dicen al servidor git quién hizo el commit y una forma de contactar al _commiter_ en caso de ser necesario. Yo haría lo mismo del ejemplo: `git config --local user.email "<>"`.